# Installing PHP extensions on Linux

Tags: php, linux

Please bear with me; I'm a developer, not a server admin. My company wants to explore using Magento. They've handed me a pre-configured Linux server with apache and PHP installed, but when I try to run the Magento setup, it tells me that there are PHP extensions that need to be loaded. I can edit the php.ini file, but have no idea where to get the extensions or how to install them, and there's no one here who knows, either.

Can anyone give me a hand? I need the PDO_MySQL, mcrypt, and GD extensions. I've searched and found sites that talk about downloading from the terminal and compiling code, but it's all way over my head. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://pear.php.net/

Often Linux system have the pear application in repository, so you would just need to run a command for each extension you'd like to install.

Answer (score 16):

It might help to know what distro you are running, and what version of php. I'm talking about the *process* of finding packages as well since its better to know *how* to find stuff than just install what you're told. Teach an man to fish and all that.

Now, I have ubuntu and centos boxen on hand, and through the magic of the package search command....

**For Ubuntu**

I used `apt-cache search KEYWORD php` to find the packages in question - in this case the name of the plugin as the keywords. From that, you can install the 3 packages you need through `apt-get install php5-mcrypt php5-gd php5-mysql` - the last package should cover PDO on debian like distros I believe

**For Centos/Red Hat**

I used `dnf search KEYWORDS` the same way - but not all the packages you need seem available by default. Older versions of these distributions use `yum` rather than *dnf*.

The packages you're interested in are `php-pdo` `php-gd` and `php-mcrypt` - the last is *not* in the default repository (I checked on yum, then googled)- [you may need to add the EPEL repository to get that package instead](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#What_is_EPEL.3F)

Using the default package manager should result in easier to install and maintain packages, since your updates will happen with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24448.  This has all of the necessary commands and trouble shooting.

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -3):

To update the PHP Extension in Linux:

Step 1: Login as a root

step2: type--> Yum install php-xml

step3:service httpd restart // restart the service

Comment: You should invest some time into reading the question. php-xml isn't mentioned there, and by no means `yum` works on all distributions. Same for restarting services.